# Ubuntu 20.04 lagging on VirtualBox 6.1 with a lot of RAM

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I've installed an Ubuntu VM on my new laptop, but it's lagging very much, it takes seconds to open every app(terminal, mozilla, VSCode), lags on input char., scrolling down and everything. Working with this VM is really annoying.

Host OS is windows10.
I have GuestAdditions installed and I set the VM with the following parameters:

```
**Disk**
Dynamically allocated, actual size=15GB, virtual size = 100GB (out of 500GB)

**PROCESSOR**
6gb RAM (out of 16)
4 cpu cores (out of 16)

**Acceleration**
Paravirtualization Interface = default (KVM)
Nested Paging enabled

**Display**
Video Memory 64 MB (out of 128)
3D Acceleration Enabled
Graphics controller = VMSVGA
```

Do you have any idea of why it is lagging and how to fix?

Sorry in advance if I missed some information.

[image: iotop output]

[image: htop output]

Comment: Check the I/O of disk usage in HOST Machine(windows) and VM also. is there any high usage of disks or not?

Comment: Checked in both, disk usage is lower than 3%.

Comment: can you post the output of htop command

Comment: added htop and iotop output

Comment: Please add the terminal outputs as text (between three ```) instead of posting their images.

Comment: Do you see any abnormality in /var/log/messages or other logs?